# Building a Matrix With a Generator

Tags: python, generator

I have a list:

```
l = [1,2,3]
```

I want my output to be:

```
m = [(1-1, 1-2, 1-3),(2-1, 2-2, 2-3), (3-1, 3-2, 3-3)]
m = [[0, -1, -2], [1,0,-1], [-2,-1,0]]
```

I wrote this function and it works fine:

```
def matrixer(l):
    matrix = []

    for data in l:
        column = []
        column.append(data - l[0])
        column.append(data - l[1])
        column.append(data - l[2])
        matrix.append(column)

    return matrix
```

But this doesn't scale well - as my list could have up to 100's of values and I don't want to keep adding the below line of code for each value in my list:

```
column.append(data - l[n])
```

I've never used generators before but it sounds like the solution would involve one. I've always tried a while loop, but it doesn't quite get me there as I run into the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using two for loops we have to reset the `sub_answer` every time. This looks messy so maybe another option; can be found below:

```
l = [1,2,3]
answer = []
for each in l:
  sub_answer = []
  for every in l:
    sub_answer.append(each-every)
  answer.append(sub_answer)
  sub_answer = []
print(answer)
#[[0, -1, -2], [1, 0, -1], [2, 1, 0]]
```

---

Removing a for loop for a list comprehension. Now we don't need `sub_answer`:

```
l = [1,2,3]
answer = []
for each in l:
  answer.append([each-x for x in l])
print(answer)
#[[0, -1, -2], [1, 0, -1], [2, 1, 0]]
```

`l` is scale able. We are iterating through the list and then appending to a new list that we created using a list comprehension which we are subtracting the `each` variable by going through the list again.

If we change `l` to be `l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` we get:

```
[[0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6], [1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5], [2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4], [3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3], [4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1], [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]]
```

As a note `(3-1 is not -2... it's 2....)`

---

We used one list comprehension why not use two?!?!?!:
If you don't want a for loop and just want to use list comprehension:

```
l = [1,2,3]
print([[each-x for x in l] for each in l])
#[[0, -1, -2], [1, 0, -1], [2, 1, 0]]
```

gives the same result, but I think for loops are more readable if you are learning or on a team.

Answer (score 2):

double list comprehension does it in one line:

```
def matrixer(l):
    return [[e - d for d in l] for e in l]
```

- inner listcomp to create the inner line
- outer listcomp to create rows

result with your input:

```
[[0, -1, -2], [1, 0, -1], [2, 1, 0]]
```

list comprehensions are highly optimized memory-wise (less reallocations) & CPU-wise (less instructions) so replacing your double loop + append with 2 nested list comprehensions like that will speed up your code a lot.

Answer (score 2):

A short answer (shortest so far ^^) would be:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]

m = [[row - col for row in l] for col in l]
```

This uses [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.sub) like this:

```
[map(operator.sub, [item]*len(l), l) for item in l]
```

This is equivalent to:

```
matrix = []

for item in l:
    matrix.append(map(operator.sub, [item]*len(l), l))
```

**Explanation:**

For each `item` in `l`, we build a list `[item]*len(l)` and we use `map()` and `operator` to get the subtraction of these two lists. For the first element in `l` which is 1, we have:

```
[1]*3  # => [1, 1, 1]
```

Then:

```
map(operator.sub, [1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3])  # [1-1, 1-2, 1-3] => [0, -1, -2]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> import operator
>>>
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> [map(operator.sub, [item]*len(l), l) for item in l]
[[0, -1, -2], [1, 0, -1], [2, 1, 0]]
```